# Is there a way to pass the value while running Command Line Interface in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-interface, prompt

I'm trying to pass the String value argument to Command Line Interface from the client. And I'm in struggle...

The environment is :

- using spring boot and pass the file from the browser.
- controller gets file and parsing filepath and ready to pass it to CLI

However, CLI works like: when program runs by cli, it requires filepath as prompt. so if i type the valid filepath to it, it works fine.
but what i want is while program is running, client keeps requesting with file and get responses dynamically.

i searched for this problem and some answers said use observer or listener but still couldn't figure out how to pass the value while program's running and pass the value like user input..

I apologize of lack of information but I really expect little bit of help...

Comment: Just pass the file path to the programs STDIN, if that’s where it reads the program from. You may need to read the program’s STDOUT until the correct prompt appears.

Comment: Thanks for replying! but I still can't find the command to pass STDIN to Program..
I'm using Runtime to execute commands. "echo", "<" and i'm trying other command to pass a value to STDIN but I think it's wrong...